# Handel Edge case in finding the circumcenter of 3 points.[JAVA]

Tags: java

So I have done some algebra and found a formula to find the circumcenter of 3 points. I have made the code also and it works smoothly for many inputs except some edge cases where slope is 0.So my question is how to update my code to handle some edge cases. Here is my code.

```
import java.util.*;
class CircleTest
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
     int x[];
     int y[];
     int n;
     Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter the value of n");
      n=sc.nextInt();// assume n is 3 ,made this for some other reason
     x=new int[n];
     y=new int[n];
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
        x[i]=sc.nextInt();//taking 3 points as input
        y[i]=sc.nextInt();
     }
     /*
      * Assume P=(x[0],y[0])  
      * Q=(x[1],y[1])
      * R=(x[2],y[2])
      */
     double ymidPQ=(y[0]+y[1])/2.0;// y corr of mid point of PQ

     double xmidPQ=(x[0]+x[1])/2.0;// x corr. of mid point of PQ

     double slopePQ=(y[1]-y[0])/(x[1]-x[0]);// slope of line PQ



     double ymidQR=(y[1]+y[2])/2.0;

     double xmidQR=(x[1]+x[2])/2.0;

     double slopeQR=(y[2]-y[1])/(x[2]-x[1]);


     double centerY=  ( (ymidPQ * slopePQ + xmidPQ) + (ymidQR * slopeQR + xmidQR) )/(slopePQ-slopeQR);//y corr. of circumcenter

     double centerX= (ymidPQ * slopePQ+ xmidPQ ) -centerY*slopePQ;// x corr of circum center


     System.out.println(centerX+","+centerY);

    }
}
```

In the above code if three points are say,(5,0) , (0,0) and (0,5) it throws an error Division by Zero and it is quite obvious also ,so how to edit my code to handle such input also  and produce the required output(circum center).

Comment: Did you try using [Wikipedia's formulas for the circumcenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Cartesian_coordinates_2)? Those will result in an error only if no circumcenter exists (or in case of overflow, where the circumcenter is very far away from the three points).

Comment: You can make this code much more simple by moving your calculation inside a method, and removing the input handling from the question. Also, you should make clear what formula you use, and how it fails.

Answer (score -1):

Haha i was not thinking that this could be solved in such a easier way and i have just solved it.

```
import java.util.*;
class CircleTest
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
     int x[];
     int y[];
     int n;
     Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter the value of n");
      n=sc.nextInt();// assume n is 3 ,made this for some other reason
     x=new int[n];
     y=new int[n];
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
        x[i]=sc.nextInt();//taking 3 points as input
        y[i]=sc.nextInt();
     }
     /*
      * Assume P=(x[0],y[0])  
      * Q=(x[1],y[1])
      * R=(x[2],y[2])
      */
     double ymidPQ=(y[0]+y[1])/2.0;// y corr of mid point of PQ

     double xmidPQ=(x[0]+x[1])/2.0;// x corr. of mid point of PQ
     double slopePQ;
     try{ 
     slopePQ=(y[1]-y[0])/(x[1]-x[0]);// slope of line PQ
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    slopePQ=Double.MAX_VALUE;
    }


     double ymidQR=(y[1]+y[2])/2.0;

     double xmidQR=(x[1]+x[2])/2.0;

     double slopeQR;
     try{
     slopeQR=(y[2]-y[1])/(x[2]-x[1]);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    slopeQR=Double.MAX_VALUE;
    }

     double centerY=  ( (ymidPQ * slopePQ + xmidPQ) + (ymidQR * slopeQR + xmidQR) )/(slopePQ-slopeQR);//y corr. of circumcenter

     double centerX= (ymidPQ * slopePQ+ xmidPQ ) -centerY*slopePQ;// x corr of circum center


     System.out.println(centerX+","+centerY);

    }
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Please elaborate *why* this is an answer.

Comment: Slope is tan (theta) as theta tends to 90 slopes tan(theta) tends to infinity or say to  a large number . And that is what i have done if slope is parallel to y-axis i.e theta is 90 i have given slope a large value i.e Double.MAX_VALUE. @Polygnome

Comment: @Polygnome i have then tested my program against the  original input (0,0) (5,0) and (0,5) and it returned (2.5,2.5).

Comment: Then describe what is different. What has changed? Elaborate. This answer is currently just a code-dump.